# onChange function is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, onchange

This has got to be something simple. I searched the internet and only found syntax errors as the cause of this problem, but I can't find a syntax error.

Here's the javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/acrilart/javascript/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function hi(){
            alert('hi');
        }
        hi();
    });
</script>
```

And the HTML :

```
<input type="text" name="cep" value="" id="cep" class="required cep field"
       onChange="hi()" />
```

On pageload the function `hi` is called as expected, but my `onChange` event causes a Firebug error, saying the function is not defined. I'm really stumped. Did I mispell 'hi'?

Comment: Try and use `;` inside one-liner functions because the interpreter needs to know where everything ends.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but after testing I found that it works with and without the semicolon.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `hi` function is only in scope inside the `ready` event handler. Move it outside of the event handler, or handle the binding inside there (and remove the inline event handler attribute from the markup):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function hi(){
        alert('hi');
    }
    $("#cep").on("change", hi);
});
```

Answer (score 7):

The `hi` function is only defined in the `ready` block. Outside, it doesn't exist anymore.

You don't need to wrap function definitions in `.ready()`, so just remove it. Alternatively, define the function like this:

```
window.hi = function() {...}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function hi(){
            alert('hi');
        }
        hi();
    });
</script>
```

`hi` is not a global function. You can access it only inside the scope of your `function(){...}`, not from outside.

Since you are using jQuery, you can change the way you bind your function to the `onChange` event. Rather than calling it from the html tag, you can write:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function hi(){
            alert('hi');
        }
        hi();

        $('#cep').on( 'change', function(){ hi(); } );
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

`onchange` is only triggered when the control is blurred. Try `onkeypress` instead.

```
$("#cep").on("change", function() {
   alert(1);
});
```

*or*

```
<input type="text" name="cep" value="" id="cep" class="required cep field" 
onkeypress="hi()"  />
```

Use following events instead of `onchange`:

```
- onkeyup(event)
- onkeydown(event)
- onkeypress(event)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function hi(){ 
    alert('hi'); 
} 
</script>

<input type="text" name="cep" value="" id="cep" class="required cep field" onKeyPress="javascript:hi();" />
```