# Live email validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the javascript to check the email live when I'm typing in the textbox. Nothing happens.

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<form action="#" method="post" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="formulier">

            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" onchange="controle(this.value)"/>

            <div class="signup">
                <input type="button" value="Ok, Sign up!" />
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function controle(mail) {
    if (isEmail(mail.val()) == true)
        {
            alert("good");
        }

}

        function IsEmail(email) {
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
        if(!regex.test(email)) {
           return false;
        }else{
           return true;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Are you using JQuery or just plain JavaScript?

Comment: I'm jusing JQuery, but want to keep the logic with the 'onchange' in HTML

Comment: Please check my answer I've just edited it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDITED**

This JS should now work

```
function controle(mail) {
  if (IsEmail(mail) == true) {
    alert("good");
  }  
}

function IsEmail(email) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  if (!regex.test(email)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

you need to make sure this is defined outside of

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

Please check the answer to this for more info
[onChange function is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621258/onchange-function-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the event listener functions like this:

```
$("selector").on("keyup",function(){
  //your logic
})
```